# Button in kivy is not registering being clicked

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I made a custom widget and embedded a button in it. The button appears to be okay visually, but when clicked on it doesn't appear to depress or register any type of interaction with the cursor.It's definitely not a matter of bindings, it doesn't even perform its callback but I can't figure out much beyond that.The button I'm having trouble with is called x and it's in the draw function of the SubWindow class.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ReferenceListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Root(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        FloatLayout.__init__(self)
        self.add_widget(SubWindow(pos=(100, 400), size=(200, 200), color=(.25, .25, .25)))
        self.add_widget(SubWindow(pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 500), color=(.75, 0.75, .75)))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()


class SubWindow(Widget):
    tPosRel = ListProperty()
    bcolor = ListProperty()
    posOffSet = ListProperty()
    sizeOffSet = ListProperty()


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.posOffSet = [2, 2]
        self.sizeOffSet = [2, 2]
        f = kwargs['color']
        self.size = kwargs['size']
        self.pos = kwargs['pos']
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.bcolor = [f[0], f[1], f[2]]
        print(self.bcolor)
        self.fcolor = []
        i = 0
        for item in self.bcolor:
            print("i: " + str(i))
            if item >= 0.5:
                self.fcolor.append(item - .1)

            else:
                self.fcolor.append(item + .1)
            i += 1

        self.draw()


    def close(self):
        print("Closing SubWindow...")

    def draw(self, *largs):
        print("size[0]: " + str(self.size[0]))
        print("size[1]: " + str(self.size[1]))
        print("pos[0]: " + str(self.pos[0]))
        print("pos[1]: " + str(self.pos[1]))
        print(self)
        print('Drawing...')
        if len(self.children) > 0:
            self.remove_widget(self.children[0])

        x = Button(text="X", size_hint=(None, None), pos=(self.pos[0] +         self.size[0] - 21, self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 21), size=(21, 21))
        x.bind(on_release=self.close)
        #x is the button I'm having trouble with

        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.bcolor[0], self.bcolor[1], self.bcolor[2], 1)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            Color(self.fcolor[0], self.fcolor[1], self.fcolor[2], 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(self.pos[0] + 1, self.pos[1] + 1), size=(self.size[0]-2, self.size[1]-22))
        self.add_widget(x)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        #print(self.size)
        print("Mouse X: " + str(touch.x))
        print("Mouse Y: " + str(touch.y))
        if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 21 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'up'
            print("up hit detect...")
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            #self.tPosRel = touch - self.pos
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 21:
            self.side = 'right'
            print("right hit detect...")
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'down'
            print("down hit detect...")
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1]:
            self.side = 'left'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[1] - 21 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 22 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 5:
            self.side = 'window'
            self.tPosRel = (touch.x - self.pos[0], touch.y - self.pos[1])
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'leftcorner'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'rightcorner'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            touch.grab(self)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.drag(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)

    def drag(self, touch):
        def up():
            if touch.y > self.yInit + 37:
                self.size[1] = touch.y - self.pos[1]

            else:
                self.size[1] = 37

            self.draw()

        def right():
            if touch.x > self.xInit + 21:
                self.size[0] = touch.x - self.pos[0]

            else:
                self.size[0] = 21

            self.draw()

        def down():
            if touch.y < self.yInit + self.hInit - 37:
                self.size[1] = self.hInit + self.yInit - touch.y
                self.pos[1] = touch.y

            else:
                self.size[1] = 37
                self.pos[1] = self.yInit + self.hInit - 37

            self.draw()

        def left():
            if touch.x < self.xInit + self.wInit - 21:
                self.size[0] = self.wInit + self.xInit - touch.x
                self.pos[0] = touch.x

            else:
                self.size[0] = 21
                self.pos[0] = self.xInit + self.wInit - 21

            self.draw()

        def window():
            print(self.tPosRel)
            self.pos = (touch.x - self.tPosRel[0], touch.y - self.tPosRel[1])
            self.draw()

        def leftcorner():
            xgood = False
            ygood = False

            if touch.x < self.xInit + self.wInit - 21:
                self.size[0] = self.wInit + self.xInit - touch.x
                self.pos[0] = touch.x
                xgood = True

            if touch.y < self.yInit + self.hInit - 37:
                self.size[1] = self.hInit + self.yInit - touch.y
                self.pos[1] = touch.y
                ygood = True

            if not xgood:
                self.size[0] = 21
                self.pos[0] = self.xInit + self.wInit - 21

            if not ygood:
                self.size[1] = 37
                self.pos[1] = self.yInit + self.hInit - 37

            self.draw()

        def rightcorner():
            xgood = False
            ygood = False

            if touch.x > self.xInit + 21:
                self.size[0] = touch.x - self.x
                xgood = True

            if touch.y < self.yInit + self.hInit - 37:
                self.size[1] = self.hInit + self.yInit - touch.y
                self.pos[1] = touch.y
                ygood = True

            if not xgood:
                self.size[0] = 21

            if not ygood:
                self.size[1] = 37
                self.pos[1] = self.yInit + self.hInit - 37

            self.draw()

        c = {'up': up, 'right': right, 'down': down, 'left': left, 'window': window, 'leftcorner': leftcorner, 'rightcorner': rightcorner}
        c[self.side]()


Factory.register('SubWindow', SubWindow)
TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. In the `on_touch_down()` method, check for collision
2. Add `return True` if consumed the touch events
3. Add `instance` to `close()` method

Please refer to the example below for details.

[Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         return True
> ```

[Grabbing touch events](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#grabbing-touch-events)

> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>
>         # if the touch collides with our widget, let's grab it
>         touch.grab(self)
>
>         # and accept the touch.
>         return True
>
> def on_touch_up(self, touch):
>     # here, you don't check if the touch collides or things like that.
>     # you just need to check if it's a grabbed touch event
>     if touch.grab_current is self:
>
>         # ok, the current touch is dispatched for us.
>         # do something interesting here
>         ...
>
>         # don't forget to ungrab ourself, or you might have side effects
>         touch.ungrab(self)
>
>         # and accept the last up
>         return True
> ```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ReferenceListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Root(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(SubWindow(pos=(100, 400), size=(200, 200), color=(.25, .25, .25)))
        self.add_widget(SubWindow(pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 500), color=(.75, 0.75, .75)))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()


class SubWindow(Widget):
    tPosRel = ListProperty()
    bcolor = ListProperty()
    posOffSet = ListProperty()
    sizeOffSet = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__()
        self.posOffSet = [2, 2]
        self.sizeOffSet = [2, 2]
        f = kwargs['color']
        self.size = kwargs['size']
        self.pos = kwargs['pos']
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.bcolor = [f[0], f[1], f[2]]
        print(self.bcolor)
        self.fcolor = []
        i = 0
        for item in self.bcolor:
            print("i: " + str(i))
            if item >= 0.5:
                self.fcolor.append(item - .1)

            else:
                self.fcolor.append(item + .1)
            i += 1

        self.draw()

    def close(self, instance):
        print("Closing SubWindow...")

    def draw(self, *largs):
        print("size[0]: " + str(self.size[0]))
        print("size[1]: " + str(self.size[1]))
        print("pos[0]: " + str(self.pos[0]))
        print("pos[1]: " + str(self.pos[1]))
        print(self)
        print('Drawing...')
        if len(self.children) > 0:
            self.remove_widget(self.children[0])

        x = Button(text="X", size_hint=(None, None), pos=(self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 21, self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 21), size=(21, 21))
        x.bind(on_release=self.close)

        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.bcolor[0], self.bcolor[1], self.bcolor[2], 1)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            Color(self.fcolor[0], self.fcolor[1], self.fcolor[2], 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(self.pos[0] + 1, self.pos[1] + 1), size=(self.size[0]-2, self.size[1]-22))
        self.add_widget(x)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return super(SubWindow, self).on_touch_down(touch)

        #print(self.size)
        print("Mouse X: " + str(touch.x))
        print("Mouse Y: " + str(touch.y))

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 21 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'up'
            print("up hit detect...")
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            #self.tPosRel = touch - self.pos
            touch.grab(self)
            return True

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 21:
            self.side = 'right'
            print("right hit detect...")
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            touch.grab(self)
            return True

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'down'
            print("down hit detect...")
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            touch.grab(self)
            return True

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1]:
            self.side = 'left'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            touch.grab(self)
            return True

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[1] - 21 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 22 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 5:
            self.side = 'window'
            self.tPosRel = (touch.x - self.pos[0], touch.y - self.pos[1])
            touch.grab(self)
            return True

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'leftcorner'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            touch.grab(self)
            return True

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
            self.side = 'rightcorner'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            self.wInit = self.size[0]
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            self.hInit = self.size[1]
            touch.grab(self)
            return True
        return super(SubWindow, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.drag(touch)
            return True

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            return True

    def drag(self, touch):
        def up():
            if touch.y > self.yInit + 37:
                self.size[1] = touch.y - self.pos[1]

            else:
                self.size[1] = 37

            self.draw()

        def right():
            if touch.x > self.xInit + 21:
                self.size[0] = touch.x - self.pos[0]

            else:
                self.size[0] = 21

            self.draw()

        def down():
            if touch.y < self.yInit + self.hInit - 37:
                self.size[1] = self.hInit + self.yInit - touch.y
                self.pos[1] = touch.y

            else:
                self.size[1] = 37
                self.pos[1] = self.yInit + self.hInit - 37

            self.draw()

        def left():
            if touch.x < self.xInit + self.wInit - 21:
                self.size[0] = self.wInit + self.xInit - touch.x
                self.pos[0] = touch.x

            else:
                self.size[0] = 21
                self.pos[0] = self.xInit + self.wInit - 21

            self.draw()

        def window():
            print(self.tPosRel)
            self.pos = (touch.x - self.tPosRel[0], touch.y - self.tPosRel[1])
            self.draw()

        def leftcorner():
            xgood = False
            ygood = False

            if touch.x < self.xInit + self.wInit - 21:
                self.size[0] = self.wInit + self.xInit - touch.x
                self.pos[0] = touch.x
                xgood = True

            if touch.y < self.yInit + self.hInit - 37:
                self.size[1] = self.hInit + self.yInit - touch.y
                self.pos[1] = touch.y
                ygood = True

            if not xgood:
                self.size[0] = 21
                self.pos[0] = self.xInit + self.wInit - 21

            if not ygood:
                self.size[1] = 37
                self.pos[1] = self.yInit + self.hInit - 37

            self.draw()

        def rightcorner():
            xgood = False
            ygood = False

            if touch.x > self.xInit + 21:
                self.size[0] = touch.x - self.x
                xgood = True

            if touch.y < self.yInit + self.hInit - 37:
                self.size[1] = self.hInit + self.yInit - touch.y
                self.pos[1] = touch.y
                ygood = True

            if not xgood:
                self.size[0] = 21

            if not ygood:
                self.size[1] = 37
                self.pos[1] = self.yInit + self.hInit - 37

            self.draw()

        c = {'up': up, 'right': right, 'down': down, 'left': left, 'window': window, 'leftcorner': leftcorner, 'rightcorner': rightcorner}
        c[self.side]()


TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]